# SUM column values with group by aggregate taking care of null values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table employees. The data is inserted as (in oracle):

```
ID  EMP_NAME    DEPT_NAME   EFFORTS ACTIVITY_DAY
633 ALEX         XYZ          30    13-May-15
633 ALEX         XYZ          30    14-May-15
633 ALEX         ABC          30    13-May-15
633 ALEX         XYZ           0    15-May-15
```

But I need to fill the efforts as 30 for a single day, e.g. here 30 has been filled twice for 13-May-15 as ALEX is there for two dept_name.
I need to modify the record like this:

```
ID  EMP_NAME    DEPT_NAME   EFFORTS ACTIVITY_DAY
633 ALEX         XYZ          30    13-May-15
633 ALEX         XYZ          30    14-May-15
633 ALEX         ABC           0    13-May-15
633 ALEX         XYZ           0    15-May-15
```

Comment: looking your data, it seems to be dept_name is different for 13-May-15. So you write simple update query using where clause. In where clause you have to use id,dept_name and activity_day. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: great.... i applied that too..but its like the record is too large and update slows the final fact population. it can do the trick but i needed something while inserting the data or a solution which might not hinder the performance.

Comment: What isn't clear from your question is *how* you want to resolve the problem of the same employee having > 30 hours on one date. In the example given, the `efforts` for department ABC were set to 0. But how is that decided? Why zero ABC and leave XYZ with 30? What rule is being applied here? What if there are more than 2 departments? What if they are each 20 minutes? The requirement needs to be clearly stated before it can be turned into SQL.

Comment: @Turophile don't take 30 as in unit of time, its something different and the table is large..i have given the portion needed for my problem. 30 is actually the distance calculation on map. ) is there because the employee has not travelled that day. 30 is default distance from a certain location after that latitude and longitude come into scene. So efault distance is to be provided for one day

Comment: and if there is a different value for efforts for the same employee on the same day, what then? how do you decide which dept_name to zero and which to keep?

Comment: OK, it isn't time, it is some other unit of effort. But the problems remain - Clearly state in generic terms what conditions you consider "wrong" and what should be done to set it right.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using, Oracle and/or MySQL? (Correct tags gives better and faster answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desired output, if I understand correctly, you want to update the `EFFORTS` column to zero when there exists more than one row for the `EMP_NAME` for a given `ACTIVITY_DAY`.

You could **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function to rank the rows with the given condition, and then update the efforts for rows with rank > 1.

Let's see:

**Setup**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

ID       EMP_ DEP    EFFORTS ACTIVITY_
-------- ---- --- ---------- ---------
633      ALEX XYZ         30 13-May-15
633      ALEX XYZ         30 14-May-15
633      ALEX ABC         30 13-May-15
633      ALEX XYZ          0 15-May-15

SQL>
```

**Driving query**

```
SQL> SELECT t.*,
  2            row_number()
  3               OVER(PARTITION BY emp_name, activity_day ORDER BY activity_day) rn
  4  FROM t;

ID       EMP_ DEP    EFFORTS ACTIVITY_         RN
-------- ---- --- ---------- --------- ----------
633      ALEX XYZ         30 13-May-15          1
633      ALEX ABC         30 13-May-15          2
633      ALEX XYZ         30 14-May-15          1
633      ALEX XYZ          0 15-May-15          1

SQL>
```

**MERGE statement to update the table**

```
SQL> MERGE INTO t
  2  USING(
  3     SELECT t.*,
  4            row_number()
  5               OVER(PARTITION BY emp_name, activity_day ORDER BY activity_day) rn
  6     FROM t
  7  ) u
  8  ON (t.ID = u.ID
  9  AND t.emp_name = u.emp_name
 10  AND t.dept_name = u.dept_name
 11  AND t.activity_day = u.activity_day)
 12  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET efforts = 0
 13  WHERE u.rn > 1;

1 row merged.

SQL>
```

**Let's check**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

ID       EMP_ DEP    EFFORTS ACTIVITY_
-------- ---- --- ---------- ---------
633      ALEX XYZ         30 13-May-15
633      ALEX XYZ         30 14-May-15
633      ALEX ABC          0 13-May-15
633      ALEX XYZ          0 15-May-15

SQL>
```

So, this gives the desired output.

Comment: Had to do little tweaking according to my dataset and it worked perfectly